# Elasticsearch failed to update snapshot in repository error

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, elastic-stack, snapshot

I am using the Elasticsearch API snapshot endpoint to take backups, it was working fine for me but suddenly I am getting this error -

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "snapshot_exception",
        "reason" : "[my_s3_repository:daily_backup_202205160300/yvQaLO25SQam8NU3PF7aSQ] failed to update snapshot in repository"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "snapshot_exception",
    "reason" : "[my_s3_repository:daily_backup_202205160300/yvQaLO25SQam8NU3PF7aSQ] failed to update snapshot in repository",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "i_o_exception",
      "reason" : "Unmatched second part of surrogate pair (0xDE83)",
      "suppressed" : [
        {
          "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason" : "Failed to close the XContentBuilder",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "i_o_exception",
            "reason" : "Unclosed object or array found"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

This is the command I am using

`curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_s3_repository/daily_backup_202205160300?wait_for_completion=true"`

Any ideas why this is happening?